# How to style 5 different WordPress post groups

Tags: php, wordpress, styles

I am trying to add the same class to the group of 5 posts

For example:

```
<div class="a">
 - article 1
 - article 2
 - article 3
 - article 4
 - article 5
  </div>
<div class="a">
 - article 6
 - article 7
 - article 8
 - article 9
 - article 10
  </div>
```

This is my code:

```
<?php $owl = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type'=>'post',
'post_status'=>'publish',
'orderby' => 'ID',
'order' => 'DESC',
 'posts_per_page'=> 10));
    ?>
 <?php $i = 0; while ($owl->have_posts()) : $owl->the_post(); ?>
<div class="a">
 <?php if($i < 6){ ?>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
 <?php } ?></div>
 <div class="a">
<?php if($i > 5){ ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
  <?php } ?></div>
 <?php $i++; endwhile ; wp_reset_query() ;?>
```

It does not work as I would like. What I am doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
<?php
    $owl = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'=>'post',
        'post_status'=>'publish',
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page'=> 10
    ));
?>
<div class="a">
<?php $i = 0; while ($owl->have_posts()) : $owl->the_post(); ?>
<?php if($i == 6){ ?>
    </div>
    <div class="a">
<?php } ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>
<?php
    $i++;
    endwhile;
?>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: You are most welcome Glad that I was able to help you.